# roll-over buttons in sepearate folder

Tags: javascript

This works:

```
<div>
<a href="javascript:openNewWindow1()"><img src="button-normal.gif"
 alt="Button" style="width:300px;height:50px;border:none;" 
 onmouseover="this.src='button-hover.gif'"
 onmouseout="this.src='button-normal.gif'"
 onclick="this.src='button-click.gif'"
 ></a>
 </div>
```

The buttons are in the same directory as the html file. But I want to out the three buttons in a folder (called buttons) but when I do that I cannot make it work. ie 
     `onmouseout="this.src='buttons/button-normal.gif'"`

does not do it.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: Is your buttons folder and html file in same directory?

Comment: If you are trying to do rollovers/active then CSS would probably be a better option.

Comment: What you have seems to work for me, check the console output for the paths it's hitting. https://jsfiddle.net/je41hjxw/

Comment: Charlie's fiddle now works for me; don't know what was wrong before. Many Thanks.